# getting fatal error:Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\mhy\dilwale.php on line 21

Tags: php

Getting this error:

> fatal error:Object of class mysqli could not be    converted to string
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\mhy\dilwale.php on line 21,that is following

I have written below  code to upload image on database,for following form dil.html

php code dilwale.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$databse     ="mydb";
   // Create connection
$conn =  mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);


// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else
{
echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
mysqli_select_db("$databse","$conn");
$imagename=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$imagedata=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
echo "$imagedata";
 }
?>
```

I have written above code to upload image on database,for following form dil.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="dilwale.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name ="image" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: only `$conn`, not `"$conn"`.

Comment: please ingnore first line of code,it is the line where error occuring

Comment: then that is exactly where you should be looking. try the change I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **""** from the variables. $conn is an object and can't be converted to a string. So you cant use "$conn".
 Replace the line with this:

```
mysqli_select_db($databse,$conn);
```

Your problem will be gone.